# Getting a WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop Signal Catcher after couple of seconds the service starts

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am creating a Xamarin app that collects sensordata so I can experiment with it using machine learning. The app is using an intentservice in the background.. but after a couple of seconds i get the following error:

03-23 21:31:14.772 I/zygote64(18051): Thread[3,tid=18057,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x7dabcc0400,peer=0x13fc0088,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
03-23 21:31:14.772 I/zygote64(18051): 
03-23 21:31:14.772 E/zygote64(18051): # HandleSigQuit # DumpForSigQuit # before # pid=18051
03-23 21:31:14.879 E/zygote64(18051): # HandleSigQuit # DumpForSigQuit # after # pid=18051
03-23 21:31:14.883 I/zygote64(18051): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

I am debugging on a Oneplus 3T with android 8.0.0.
The sensordata is directly written into a sqlite database with the sqlite-net ORM.

I have tried debugging for 9 hours now.. but i can't fix the error.
when i comment out the service.. it doesn't give me any errors.

This is how my service looks like:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Hardware;
using Tabi.DataStorage;
using Tabi.DataObjects;

namespace Tabi.Droid.CollectionService
{
    [Service]
    public class SensorService : IntentService, ISensorEventListener
    {
        private readonly ISensorRepository<Accelerometer> _accelerometerRepository;
        private readonly ISensorRepository<Gyroscope> _gyroscopeRepository;
        private readonly ISensorRepository<Magnetometer> _magnetometerRepository;
        private readonly ISensorRepository<LinearAcceleration> _linearAccelerationRepository;
        private readonly ISensorRepository<Orientation> _orientationRepository;
        private readonly ISensorRepository<Quaternion> _quaternionRepository;
        private readonly ISensorRepository<Gravity> _gravityRepository;


        public SensorService()
        {
            _accelerometerRepository = App.RepoManager.AccelerometerRepository;
            _gyroscopeRepository = App.RepoManager.GyroscopeRepository;
            _magnetometerRepository = App.RepoManager.MagnetometerRepository;
            _linearAccelerationRepository = App.RepoManager.LinearAccelerationRepository;
            _orientationRepository = App.RepoManager.OrientationRepository;
            _quaternionRepository = App.RepoManager.QuaternionRepository;
            _gravityRepository = App.RepoManager.GravityRepository;
        }


        public void OnAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, [GeneratedEnum] SensorStatus accuracy)
        {

        }

        public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent e)
        {
            //start gathering data and push to SqliteDB
            switch (e.Sensor.Type)
            {
                case SensorType.Accelerometer:
                     _accelerometerRepository.Add(new Accelerometer()
                    {
                        Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now,
                        X = e.Values[0],
                        Y = e.Values[1],
                        Z = e.Values[2],
                    });
                    break;

                case SensorType.Gyroscope:
                    _gyroscopeRepository.Add(new Gyroscope()
                    {
                        Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now,
                        X = e.Values[0],
                        Y = e.Values[1],
                        Z = e.Values[2],
                    });
                    break;

                case SensorType.MagneticField:
                    _magnetometerRepository.Add(new Magnetometer()
                    {
                        Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now,
                        X = e.Values[0],
                        Y = e.Values[1],
                        Z = e.Values[2],
                    });
                    break;

                case SensorType.Orientation:
                    _orientationRepository.Add(new Orientation()
                    {
                        Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now,
                        X = e.Values[0],
                        Y = e.Values[1],
                        Z = e.Values[2]
                    });
                    break;

                case SensorType.Gravity:
                    _gravityRepository.Add(new Gravity()
                    {
                        Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now,
                        X = e.Values[0],
                        Y = e.Values[1],
                        Z = e.Values[2]
                    });
                    break;

                case SensorType.LinearAcceleration:
                    _linearAccelerationRepository.Add(new LinearAcceleration()
                    {
                        Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now,
                        X = e.Values[0],
                        Y = e.Values[1],
                        Z = e.Values[2]
                    });
                    break;

                case SensorType.RotationVector:
                    _quaternionRepository.Add(new Quaternion
                    {
                        Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now,
                        X = e.Values[0],
                        Y = e.Values[1],
                        Z = e.Values[2],
                        W = e.Values[3]
                    });
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            var sensorManager = (SensorManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.SensorService);

            Sensor accelerometer = sensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.Accelerometer);
            sensorManager.RegisterListener(this, accelerometer, SensorDelay.Normal);

            Sensor gyroscope = sensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.Gyroscope);
            sensorManager.RegisterListener(this, gyroscope, SensorDelay.Normal);

            Sensor magnetometer = sensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.MagneticField);
            sensorManager.RegisterListener(this, magnetometer, SensorDelay.Normal);

            //sensor fusion
            //linear acceleration
            Sensor linearAcceleration = sensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.LinearAcceleration);
            sensorManager.RegisterListener(this, linearAcceleration, SensorDelay.Normal);

            //gravity
            Sensor gravity = sensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.Gravity);
            sensorManager.RegisterListener(this, gravity, SensorDelay.Normal);

            //pitch yaw roll / orientation
            Sensor orientation = sensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.Orientation);
            sensorManager.RegisterListener(this, orientation, SensorDelay.Normal);

            //quaternion
            Sensor rotationVector = sensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.RotationVector);
            sensorManager.RegisterListener(this, rotationVector, SensorDelay.Normal);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Your `IntentService` is being killed by the OS due to the execution limits imposed by API-8+. An `IntentService` is not intended to be long running services, they are designed to handle an inbound intent not to be setup to become listeners. Use a *foregrounded* Service instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How can i use a service that is not on the ui thread and can run in the background on android 8+?

Comment: Use a foregrounded Service and spin a thread off.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue after more than 12 hours of debugging!
I have changed the service from intentservice to normal service.
The rest of the sensordata is obtained in a second service.
it seems that blocks of code like these are a bottleneck:

```
 _magnetometerRepository.Add(new Magnetometer()
                        {
                            Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now,
                            X = e.Values[0],
                            Y = e.Values[1],
                            Z = e.Values[2],
                        });
```

This is my final result:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Hardware;
using Tabi.DataStorage;
using Tabi.DataObjects;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Tabi.Droid.CollectionService
{
    [Service]
    public class SensorService : Service, ISensorEventListener
    {
        private readonly ISensorRepository<Accelerometer> _accelerometerRepository;
        private readonly ISensorRepository<Gyroscope> _gyroscopeRepository;
        private readonly ISensorRepository<Magnetometer> _magnetometerRepository;

        private SensorServiceBinder _binder;

        public SensorService()
        {
            _accelerometerRepository = App.RepoManager.AccelerometerRepository;
            _gyroscopeRepository = App.RepoManager.GyroscopeRepository;
            _magnetometerRepository = App.RepoManager.MagnetometerRepository;
        }


        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            // service binder is used to communicate with the service
            _binder = new SensorServiceBinder(this);
            return _binder;
        }

        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            //!!!possibly needed for android 8+
            // maybe convert it into foreground service and uncomment code below
            //Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(Application.Context, "com.tabi.sensor");
            //builder.SetContentTitle("sensor");
            //builder.SetContentText("you are being watched -.-");
            //builder.SetAutoCancel(true);

            //Notification notification = builder.Build();
            //StartForeground(1, notification);


            //register sensors for listening
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var sensorManager = (SensorManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.SensorService);

                Sensor accelerometer = sensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.Accelerometer);
                sensorManager.RegisterListener(this, accelerometer, SensorDelay.Normal);

                Sensor gyroscope = sensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.Gyroscope);
                sensorManager.RegisterListener(this, gyroscope, SensorDelay.Normal);

                Sensor magnetometer = sensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.MagneticField);
                sensorManager.RegisterListener(this, magnetometer, SensorDelay.Normal);
            });

            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }

        public void OnAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, [GeneratedEnum] SensorStatus accuracy)
        {

        }

        public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent e)
        {
            //start gathering data and push to SqliteDB
            switch (e.Sensor.Type)
            {
                case SensorType.Accelerometer:
                    Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        _accelerometerRepository.Add(new Accelerometer()
                        {
                            Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now,
                            X = e.Values[0],
                            Y = e.Values[1],
                            Z = e.Values[2],
                        });
                        Console.WriteLine("accelerometer: X:" + e.Values[0] + " Y" + e.Values[1] + " Z:" + e.Values[2]);
                    });
                    break;

                case SensorType.Gyroscope:
                    Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        _gyroscopeRepository.Add(new Gyroscope()
                        {
                            Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now,
                            X = e.Values[0],
                            Y = e.Values[1],
                            Z = e.Values[2],
                        });
                    });
                    Console.WriteLine("Gyroscope: X:" + e.Values[0] + " Y" + e.Values[1] + " Z:" + e.Values[2]);
                    break;

                case SensorType.MagneticField:
                    Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        _magnetometerRepository.Add(new Magnetometer()
                        {
                            Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now,
                            X = e.Values[0],
                            Y = e.Values[1],
                            Z = e.Values[2],
                        });
                    });
                    Console.WriteLine("magnetometer: X:" + e.Values[0] + " Y" + e.Values[1] + " Z:" + e.Values[2]);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to SushiHangover for gaving me the idea of threading!